# Consulta de Entity Framework c# con dos tipos de datos

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lambda

quiero saber si tengo estos dos valores en mi tabla para verificacion el ***tipo de dato me sale error***

```
using (RARGEntities datosEntity = new RARGEntities())
{
    RegistroDatos datos = datosEntity.RegistroDatos.Where(x => x.CodPersona == CodPersona && x.FechaEntrada = Fecha).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te falta un igual FechaEntrada == Fecha

Comment: En la condicion de fecha estas asignando no comparando (`x.FechaEntrada = Fecha`)